# Use migrate to populate entity_reference with nid

Tags: 8, entities, migrations

I am migrating a D6 site to D8. The D6 site used the "Node Relativity" module, which has been broken for a while. It was used to establish a link between two content types, which I will call `meeting` and `recording`.

Now I am trying to use the `migrate` module (and friends like `migrate_plus`) to establish an entity reference to `recording` in the `meeting` content type. Here is what I have done:

- In the D8 site, specified the field structure for the two content types. In the `meeting` content type there is an entity reference for the `recording` called `field_recording_link`.
- Exported the configuration into custom modules. I can now create a database from scratch and it creates the content types.
- Connected my D6 database to import content. Textfields from the `meeting` content type do get imported.
- Written a custom source module with a `prepareRow()` method that exposes the NID of the `recording` nodes (called `recording_nid`). I can see this NID in the migration.

In the `migrate_plus.migration.upgrade_d6_node_meeting.yml` file, added the following stanza in the `process` section:

```
field_recording_link: recording_nid
```

but this does not populate the field. I have also tried:

```
'field_recording_link/target_id': recording_nid
```

but that does not work either. I feel as if this ought to be straightforward, but I am pretty stuck.

- Do I need to make a process plugin? If so what should it do? Use PHP to create an entity reference and populate it?
- Do I need to call an existing process plugin? If so which one?
- Do I have to write a separate `.yml` file just for this field? If so what would it look like? I have been looking around for examples but have not had much luck.

I would appreciate any advice you have, as well as links to examples of this.

Answer (score 4):

It was straightforward. I had a typo in my YML file. The correct answer was:

```
field_recording_link/target_id: recording_nid
```

The important thing is to set the `target_id` field, since that is what the entity reference really is.